# Crystal Reports, wrapping text on specific character

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, word-wrap

Version: Crystal Reports Developer XI

I have a single field in a crystal report that could potentially return 100's of codes separated by colons. I would like to wrap this field so that each line always ends in a colon (:), i.e. it does not wrap mid code. Could this could be achieved using a Can Grow formula?

*Example*

Current Display:

```
123:456:5
67:891:AB
C:DEF:GHI
J:987:654:
```

Required Display:

```
123:456:
567:891:
ABC:DEF:
GHIJ:987:
654:
```

The codes are between 7-9 alphanumeric characters long and in the space available 2/3 codes will fit per line. The Can Grow setting is currently set to 0 (unlimited).

Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
local stringvar array data := split("123:456:567:891:ABC:DEF:GHIJ:987:654:",":");
local stringvar s;
local stringvar CRLF := chr(10)+ chr(13);
Local numbervar i;
local numbervar iter:=1;

for i := 1 to ubound(data) do (

    // serialize
    s := s + data[i] + ":";

    // if even-numbered iteration, add line break
    if remainder(iter,2)=0 then s:= s + CRLF;

    // increment counter
    iter:=iter+1;

);

// return result
s;
```